# What positive thing can "isn't going anywhere" convey?

Tags: meaning

In [this](https://www.coinbase.com/blog/a-message-from-ceo-and-co-founder-brian-armstrong-to-coinbase-employees) public "message from CEO and Co-Founder" for a cryptocurrency exchange company, it's stated:

> crypto[currency] isn't going anywhere.

What positive thing about cryptocurrency (if any) is that intended to convey?

Comment: Yeah, well, those guys are pretty crude. You can look that up in the Urban Dictionary. "isn't going anywhere" is a way to say: is here to stay.

Comment: @Lambie: another [good source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not_going_anywhere) attesting moreless your suggested meaning ("Dependable; not inclined to leave or bail out unexpectedly"), which makes sense. Funny it also gives the alternate "Not making progress". This is what I had read. A case of confirmation bias, I guess…

Comment: Yes, it's true that it **can mean** not making progress but used sarcastically by crypto-dudes, I think not. Good find, though.

Answer (score 1):

"*[x] isn't going anywhere*" is negative, or positive, depending on whether the thing you are talking about is *supposed* to go somewhere! The positive meaning is usually an implication of *steadfastness* or *longevity*.

**Negative example:**

> This conversation isn't going anywhere.

This usually means that the conversation is *not progressing*. It is not achieving anything, perhaps because the other party is being obtuse.

**Positive example:**

> There's no hurry, it's not going anywhere.

This is sometimes said to reassure someone that something will still be around for some time to come.

With your specific example of cryptocurrency, some wider context would be needed. Some people see cryptocurrency as a *speculative investment*, that is they hope it will increase in value. If that is the quality under discussion then 'not going anywhere' might be a negative thing, suggesting that the particular currency is not increasing in value. Alternatively, some people see cryptocurrency as a long-term secure system of currency, while its detractors may say that it is just a novelty with no real future. If that was the quality under discussion then 'not going anywhere' could be a suggestion that it is here to stay. Really then, this one could be either negative or positive, depending on the context.